# cordova: "unfortunately app stopped"; also memory not released (on disk)

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to use cordova to run an application. Each time it tells me that "unfortunately app stopped".

Plus, the memory on disk is not released when the helloworld2 app fails to run: I have to delete some files from time to time cause cordova tells me that there's no more space on disk and so on.

Can someone give me a hint on what may be happening? I'm using Arch by the way as an operating system.

I issued these commands:

```
cordova create hello2 com.example.hello helloworld2
cordova platoform add android
cordova build android
cordova emulate android
```

The emulator runs and tells me after a while that "unfortunately the application helloworld2 has stopped".

This is the config.ini for the emulator:

```
avd.ini.encoding=ISO-8859-1
abi.type=armeabi-v7a
disk.dataPartition.size=200M
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.front=emulated
hw.cpu.arch=arm
hw.cpu.model=cortex-a8
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.hash2=MD5:d3c9ed02af441ec949711439b9a48b85
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=Nexus 7
hw.gps=yes
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.lcd.density=213
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.ramSize=1024
hw.sdCard=no
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=no
hw.trackBall=no
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-19/android-wear/armeabi-v7a/
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=800x1280
skin.path=800x1280
snapshot.present=true
tag.display=Android Wear
tag.id=android-wear
vm.heapSize=32
```

The application is standard from the cordova examples set as I understand but ill include it here just in case:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the js file:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

And finally this is the build output:

```
this is me on this line: cordova emulate android
Running command: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator
Buildfile: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.3
 [checkenv] Installed at /opt/android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: helloworld2
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for helloworld2...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/ant-build/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/ant-build/rsLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for helloworld2...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.3
 [checkenv] Installed at /opt/android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaLib
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaLib...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/rsLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaLib...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found modified input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found new input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/ant-build/classes

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
      [dex] input: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-5c7cefdf4b27f91c57d1b79218836f79.jar <- /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] Found modified input file
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/ant-build/classes.dex...
       [dx] Merged dex A (7 defs/2.2KiB) with dex B (206 defs/314.1KiB). Result is 213 defs/385.4KiB. Took 0.3s

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Found modified input file
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...

-package:
[apkbuilder] Found modified input file
[apkbuilder] Creating helloworld2-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/ant-build/helloworld2-debug.apk
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/ant-build/build.prop

-post-build:
     [move] Moving 1 file to /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/ant-build
     [move] Moving 1 file to /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build

debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to mobile06
Waiting for emulator...
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Booting up emulator (this may take a while).........................BOOT COMPLETE
Installing app on emulator...
Using apk: /srv/http/proj04/cordova/hello2/platforms/android/ant-build/helloworld2-debug-unaligned.apk
Launching application...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply use the adb tools instead of the emulator (in the sense that I run the code on my phoen):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/android.

easy.